# Define a generator which updates global variables before the first __next__() call

Tags: python, oop, generator

Given the following function in python I would like to update the global variable before calling "**next**()". Let me show it to you with an example.

```
# some script happening before
 
# a (global) variable is created
L = 0

def generate(batch=128, ID=0, YIND=0):

  # just a call to a global dictionary
  x_, y_ = global_dict[id_to_keys[ID]]

  # update global variable please
  global L
  L = len(x_)

  X,Y=[],[]
  counter=0

  for i,x in enumerate(x_):

    counter+=1
    X.append(x)
    Y.append(y_[i])

    if counter==batch: 

      counter=0
      yield np.asarray(X[-batch:]), np.asarray(Y[-batch:])
```

Then you can run:

```
print(L)
g = generate()
print(f'I would like this to output some number but it outputs ',L)
_ = g.__next__()
print(f'I would like this to output some number and it outputs ',L)
```

Which outputs the following:

```
I would like this to output some number but it outputs 0
I would like this to output some number and it outputs 12312
```

Finally: please note that there is a way of doing this via a class definition that has a class variable, but I'm currently wondering for a full "functional" implementation.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not entirely sure if I understand correctly what you are trying to do. But the thing is that a generator function in Python only starts to execute once the generator is being enumerated:

```py
def gen():
    print('before 1')
    yield 1
    print('before 2')
    yield 2
    print('after 2')
```

```py
>>> g = gen()
>>> next(g)
before 1
1
>>> next(g)
before 2
2
>>> next(g)
after 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    next(g)
StopIteration
```

So if you want to run code *before* the generator is being enumerated, you cannot have that code be part of the generator function itself.

What you can do instead is to have a normal function that does something and then returns a created generator:

```py
def gen_internal():
    yield 1
    print('before 2')
    yield 2
    print('after 2')

def gen():
    print('before 1')
    return gen_internal()
```

```py
>>> g = gen()
before 1
>>> next(g)
1
>>> next(g)
before 2
2
>>> next(g)
after 2
```

Since you apparently only set `L` once, before the first yield, this might be what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, you have understood correctly. I will accept this answer because it does exactly what I have stated I want to do.